# Http Bad Request - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, api, post, httprequest

My POST call to this API is giving me a 400. It is giving a syntax error even though the serialized DTO object is correct. The requestbody is using correct fieldnames which are corresponding to fieldnames in class.

Also the ApI is not even getting hit.

In headers, content-type : application/json

My API is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/surveymonkey/webhook/receiver", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void respondToSurveyMonkeyPOSTCall(@RequestBody NPSWebhookRequestBody npsWebhookRequestBody, HttpServletRequest request) {


        String objectType = null;

        String objectId =null;

        if(npsWebhookRequestBody!=null){

            objectType = npsWebhookRequestBody.getObjectType();

            objectId = npsWebhookRequestBody.getObjectId();
        }

        service.getCall(objectType,objectid
    }
```

My DTO class which is serialized to requestbody is :

```
package com.lk.scheduler.beans;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class NPSWebhookRequestBody {

    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("event_id")
    String eventId;

    @SerializedName("object_type")
    String objectType;

    @SerializedName("object_id")
    String objectId;

    @SerializedName("event_type")
    String eventType;

    @SerializedName("event_datetime")
    String eventDatetime;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventId
     */
    public String getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventId the eventId to set
     */
    public void setEventId(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the objectType
     */
    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    /**
     * @param objectType the objectType to set
     */
    public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the objectId
     */
    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    /**
     * @param objectId the objectId to set
     */
    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventType
     */
    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventType the eventType to set
     */
    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventDatetime
     */
    public String getEventDatetime() {
        return eventDatetime;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventDatetime the eventDatetime to set
     */
    public void setEventDatetime(String eventDatetime) {
        this.eventDatetime = eventDatetime;
    }



}
```

Postman call which is giving 400 :

[image]

P.S. : HttpGET and HttpHEAD call to this API is working.

Comment: what are your application's log files showing?

Comment: Have you tried sending it as form-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was by sheer luck that I found the error. Apparently Spring's **@RequestBody** annotation does not work for serialization-deserialization using Google's gson library.

@SerializedName(which is Gson's annotation property) will not work at the time of deserialization and thus a 400 bad request as request body could not be resolved..

We can use @JsonProperty of fasterxml-jackson. It works fine and the API is giving 200 response.